# How to use directory as an arg for a function in R

Tags: r, csv

I'm working on an assignment and the function I'm to write has 3 args: the directory that contains the tables to be evaluated, the column to be evaluated by the function, and a sequence 1:x where x is the number of files in the directory.

My confusion is rather fundamental, as I am not sure if the directory that the function needs to work with needs to be set to my working directory, or if the directory needs to have the entire file path.

Ideally, I would want to call the function pm("folder name", "colname", 4:112 ##random seq) and whatever math that happens in the function occur.

Unfortunately, my knowledge of syntax is a bit lacking and at the moment I'm trying to change the sequence the user inputs to match the file names, so I can use a read.csv script to read in only the tables that match the sequence defined by the user.

```
pm<-function(directory, sex, id = 1:440){ ##sex is the col arg M/F
i<-id
j<-as.character(i)
j[nchar(j)==1]<-paste("00", j[nchar(j)==1], sep="")
j[nchar(j)==2]<-paste("0", j[nchar(j)==2], sep="")   
j[nchar(j)==3]<-paste(j[nchar(j)==3],".csv", sep="")
print(j)
}
```

This is my current plan to convert the user input from the 1:400 sequence to a character vector and use it to read the specific tables I need. Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: It might be easier to use `dir(directory, full.names = TRUE)` to get all the full paths to the files.  And yes, the working directory should be set to wherever the directory is (easiest).

Comment: The alternative to Richard S' good suggestion is to do (inside your function)  `foo<-read.csv(paste0(directory,filename))` or the equivalent after you've assembled the file names as character strings.

Comment: Will I be required to read.csv the tables into R, regardless of what the path of the function's directory argument? If so, how do omit tables that aren't in the sequence the user inputs?

Comment: `file.path` is a bit safer than `paste0` when building file paths as it should be more careful with the directory separators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than counting characters yourself, let formatC do it for you.

```
pm <- function(directory, sex, id = 1:440){
  filenames <- paste0(formatC(id, digits = 0, width = 3, format="f", flag = "0"), ".csv")
  filepaths <- file.path(directory, filenames)
  list_of_data_frames <- lapply(filepaths, read.csv)

  # Do things with the data here, such as lapply(list_of_data_frames, your_function)

}
```

Comment: This mostly works and I have the entire function evaluating as intended, but I have a problem with the id arg. If the id value is an integer over 9 I receive the following error message: "Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file 'specdata/1e+01.csv': No such file or directory

Comment: If I enter an integer 1-9 or a sequence, the function works perfectly.

Comment: e.g. when id=30 the error says "cannot open 'specdata/3e+01.csv'"

Comment: @efridge I added 'format="f"', which will specify to not use scientific notation. What OS and R version are you using? I am wondering why it defaulted to scientific notation.

Comment: I'm on OS X Mavericks and R 3.1. I used format="d" and it also worked.